# Dropdownmenu select by GetElementById is not working VB

Tags: vb.net

I want create a website autofiller.

The Homepage has a DropDownMenu with 20 or more characters (Countries)

```
<select id="foo_pre_reg_country" name="foo_pre_reg_country" style="/*display:none;*/">
    <option value="AFG">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="EGY">Ägypten</option>
    <option value="ALA">Åland</option>
    <option value="ALB">Albanien</option>
    <option value="DZA">Algerien</option>
    <option value="ASM">Amerikanisch-Samoa</option>
</select>
```

Where I can select an ID with `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("foo_pre_reg_country"....`
Sorry for my bad English and thank you for helping me.

Answer (score -1):

the html code is:

```html
<select id="foo_pre_reg_country" name="foo_pre_reg_country" style="/*display:none;*/">
    <option value="AFG">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="EGY">Ägypten</option>
    <option value="ALA">Åland</option>
    <option value="ALB">Albanien</option>
    <option value="DZA">Algerien</option>
    <option value="ASM">Amerikanisch-Samoa</option>
    <option value="VIR">Amerikanische Jungferninseln</option>
    <option value="AND">Andorra</option>
    <option value="AGO">Angola</option>
    <option value="AIA">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="ATA">Antarktika</option>
    <option value="ATG">Antigua und Barbuda</option>
</select>
```

my code :`WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("foo_pre_reg_country").SetAttribute("Value", "EGY")`no working
whats the right way?